# Question regarding Fourier Series as complex exponential

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

I am learning the *Fourier Series*. It is generally represented as

$$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(nx).$$

https://youtu.be/ds0cmAV-Yek

Here Destin represents them as *circles* ,but to represent *Fourier Series* as circles we need *Complex Exponentials* ($e^{ix})$ ,but according to the video he says we use *sine terms*. Shouldn't we include *cosine terms* too?

The usage of circle to represent a diagram is beautiful ,we use vectorsthat are rotating ;placed over other vectors that are rotating at different speeds to acheive this ,does $cosine$ $terms$ get included when using circles ?

How is the below mentioned term represented as exponentials ?

This term $f(x)$=$\frac{a_o}{2}$+ $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $a_n$cos($nx$)+$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$sin($nx$). how can it be represented as an exponential ?

And is there any piece of text or video that explains *Fourier Transform* in terms of *Complex Exponentials* in an intuitive manner? I tried understanding *Grant's Video* on this topic(https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY) but it's a bit hard to understand .Is there any other source that explains *Fourier Transform* intuitively ?

Comment: Look at my edit to your post. Do not break up your LaTeX like you did. You should fix it throughout.

Comment: $A\sin{(nx)}+B\cos{(nx)}=\sqrt{A^{2}+B^{2}}\cdot\sin{(nx+\theta)}$ where $\theta = \tan^{-1}{(B/A)}$

Comment: Answering one of your questions, 
\begin{align}
\tfrac{1}{2}a_0 + \sum_n a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx &= \tfrac{1}{2}a_0 + \tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n \geqslant 1}\left\{ (a_n - ib_n) e^{inx} + (a_n + ib_n)e^{-inx} \right\} \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{inx}
\end{align}
where,
\begin{align}
c_n = \left\{ \begin{matrix}
\tfrac{1}{2}(a_n-ib_n), & n \geqslant 1 \\
\tfrac{1}{2}(a_{-n}+ib_{-n}), & n \leqslant - 1 & (= \overline c_n, \text{ if } a_n, b_n \in \mathbb R)\\
\tfrac{1}{2} a_0, & n = 0
\end{matrix}\right .
\end{align}